# Laravel Response::download() test

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, laravel-4, phpunit, mockery

I have the following code in one of my routes:

`return Response::download('cv.pdf');`

Any idea how to test this? I've tried to use shouldReceive() but that doesn't seem to work ('shouldReceive() undefined function....').

Comment: The `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response` class doesn't actually extend `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade` so doesnt have the `shouldRecieve()` method. You need to test the response of this route after calling it in a test.

Comment: @DavidBarker I tested with laravel 8 and Response facade has `shouldRecieve()` now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** As pointed by @DavidBarker in his comment to the OP question

> The Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response class doesn't actually extend
>   Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade so doesnt have the shouldRecieve()
>   method. You need to **test the response of this route** after calling it
>   in a test.

So if you want to test your download functionality, you can try checking the response for errors with:

```
$this->assertTrue(preg_match('/(error|notice)/i', $response) === false);
```

Answer (score 14):

`$response->assertDownload()` was added in Laravel 8.45.0:

> Assert that the response is a "download". Typically, this means the invoked route that returned the response returned a Response::download response, BinaryFileResponse, or Storage::download response:

> $response->assertDownload();

Learn More:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#assert-download

It does not currently (2023) allow one to test the contents of the file, but you can use test mocks for that:

```php
    public function test_successful_download(): void
    {
        $this->authenticateAsAdmin();

        $this->instance(
            ResponseFactory::class,
            Mockery::mock(ResponseFactory::class, static function(MockInterface $mock) {
                $mock
                    ->shouldReceive('download')
                    ->with('[[ FILE CONTENTS ]]', '[[ FILE NAME]]')
                    ->once()
                ;
            }),
        );

        $this->call('POST', route('my-download-csv'));
    }
```

```php
# mycontroller.php
// ...
    public function downloadCsv(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->download('[[ FILE CONTENTS ]]', '[[ FILE NAME]]');
    }
// ...
```

```
OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

Comment: Thank you for this information, but is there a way to test the "contents" of the file and not just the response headers?

Comment: (in my case, the endpoint for the download is a dynamically generated and signed file based on input parameters)

Comment: If the "content" has a mime type of `text/plain`, there might be a way to test the content. But if the content has something like `application/octet-stream` then I don't think you can test that.

Comment: Thanks. I realised what is actually happening (testing against the response object, not the output itself) and realised that what I was doing is stupid. If the content is dynamic it wouldn't be pulled from a static test file I was using, but it would be output in the content. So asserting against the content of the response I should be able to evaluate that the content is correct. Silly me, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can assert that the status code is 200

```
$this->assertEquals($response->getStatusCode(), 200);
```

because sometimes you might have some data returned that match "error" or "notice" and that would be misleading.

I additionally assert that there's an `attachment` in the response headers:

```
$this->assertContains('attachment', (string)$response);
```

Comment: For those from 2020:
`$this->assertEquals('attachment; filename=cv.pdf', $response->headers->get('content-disposition'));`

Comment: For those from 2023: `$response->assertHeader('content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=cv.pdf');`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Mockery` to mock the `download` method, for this you will need to mock `ResponseFactory`.

```
public function testDownloadCsv()
{
    $this->instance(
        ResponseFactory::class, Mockery::mock(ResponseFactory::class, function ($mock) {
        $mock->shouldReceive('download')
            ->once()
            ->andReturn(['header' => 'data']);
    }));

    $response = $this->get('/dowload-csv');

    $response->assertStatus(Response::HTTP_OK);
    $response->assertJson(['header' => 'data']); // Response
}
```